# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domElement')

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new with three.js and I don't know what's the probleme is

```
    <script type="node_modules" src="./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="node_modules" src="./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
      let scene, camera, renderer;

      function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
        camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
        camera.position.x = 800;
        camera.position.y = 100;
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

        hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
        scene.add(hlight);
        directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
        directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
        directionalLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(directionalLight);
        light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light.position.set(0,300,500);
        scene.add(light);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('./test_3d/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
          car = gltf.scene.children[0];
          car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
          scene.add(gltf.scene);
          animate();
        });
      }


      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      init();
```

and it return me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'domElement')
at init ((index):25:61)

which refers to this part of the code:

`controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. `renderer` is clearly undefined at this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Sebastian summed this up in the comment but I'll go ahead and post so if its still unclear you can get an explanation. You initialize the variable renderer on this line:

```js
let scene, camera, renderer;
```

but there is nothing inside that variable until you initialize the renderer here:

```js
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
```

So when you call on the renderer for orbitControls here:

```js
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

You are trying to call the renderer variable with nothing in it yet. A simple fix to this would just be to move the code for your controls under the code for the renderer

Comment: There are quite a few other things going on here that are going to cause you some issues. Remember to always declare your variables